# Import data manually into Azure Spatial Anchors to display a virtual object

Tags: azure, augmented-reality, point-clouds, azure-spatial-anchors

I am looking to display a virtual object in the real world using Azure Spatial Anchors technology. To do this, I have this virtual object and a point cloud of the scene made with a laser scanner. I would like to know if it is possible to manually integrate these data into the Azure Cloud so that the virtual object can be displayed in the scene later. To do this, I would use Unity to define an anchor (center of the coordinate system) relative to the virtual object and relative to the point cloud. These data would then be imported into the Azure Cloud, and I could use it to have Azure Spatial Anchors match this point cloud with the feature points found in the scene during the session. Does Azure Spatial Anchors allow this?

Comment: Relates with: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/690659/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ASA does not support users to upload their own point clouds for matching later. Instead ASA collects the environment information from the native platform tracker at the time of creating spatial anchor and use it later for matching.

Comment: Please add a new Feature Request in [feedback.azure.com | Azure Spatial Anchors](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/f47d9b25-0725-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8#) and share it here so others can vote for it. Thanks.